# How does difficulty increase in arcade mode?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

I'm still playing arcade mode in "hard" difficulty, a rather easy one.  Why?  Because the last opponent (Seth) and the special "rival" opponent (*"Now, fight you rival"* - Ryu, in my case) are super hard to beat, while all the previous fighters are simply ridiculous.  Whilst I can manage the "rival", Seth is a real problem to me.

Is it because

- Akuma is a particularly weak matchup against Seth?
- There is a crazy increase of difficulty during the endgame, like the rival is one level above the selected difficulty, and the final boss is 2 levels above?  Since I can easily beat Ryu or Seth when I create a match against one of them in this difficulty, it seems pretty credible.
- I just suck like hell?

Does anyone know how the difficulty increases in arcade mode (especially in the endgame)?

Comment: It isn't a matchup thing.  Seth is an SNK boss:http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SNKBoss

Comment: Once you realize that you just have to change your tactics to be super defensive and counter him when he jumps in, which he likes to do a lot.  The only chars I've found to have a hard time are the ones with weak anti air moves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple things I've figured:

1. The prediction of moves becomes a lot more often, and much quicker.  At easy mode, bots will take more time to respond to moves, and have a higher delay between attacks.  At hard mode, bots are literally attacking you based on your input.  To test this, I had an Abel vs Ryu match-up, in Hard mode.   By spamming cr.HK constantly, nearly 9/10 times the Ryu would counter with Shoryuken/EX Shoryuken, or an EX Tatsumaki.  This means that in Hard mode, you need to play a tad more defensively.
2. Bots go full offense in Hard mode.  In real gameplay between players, there is a lot more footsie action and neutral game.  In Arcade mode, bots will constantly throw out attacks, and there is no footsie game.  This means you need to know frame data, know what is punishable.   If you stay back a distance, shoto characters will spam fireballs.  If you get close, they may try throws/grapples/sweep. Know the matchup and know when your moves will hit over another char's moves (especially Seth's, in SSFIV a lot of his moves have HUGE frame advantage

That's all I have for now.